# What is mathematical analysis?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, symbolic-logic, foundations-of-mathematics

Hilbert's aim to reduce all mathematics to finite logical system was shown impossible by Goedel. He did mathematical analysis of logic itself (Goedel numbering). Turing defined algorithms, and mathematised (algorithms are objects of study in mathematics/cs) them as well -to solve halting problem, and formalise computation (and there goes the possibility of reducing mathematics to algorithms).

The issue which bothers me is what *is* "mathematical" analysis (or treatment)? What makes one treatment/analysis *mathematical* ? Now it is possible to do mathematics in natural language (it will be very long and tedious, but in principle, one only has to follow reasoning as outlined in the write-up). So is mathematical treatment a "style"? Is it the rigour? Is it formalisation?

Edit: I would call Turing's analysis as *mathematical* -bringing algorithms under the purview of mathematical techniques. This is the sense of "mathematical analysis" in this question (not to be confused with real analysis, etc.).

Comment: Please give the original context where the term 'mathematical analysis' is used. Otherwise there are several answers possible about the use of the term.

Comment: Although Godel showed that the hope of *computably* deriving all arithmetical truths from a finite set of axioms won't work (at least not if you believe all well-formed formulas of first-order arithmetic must have a truth-value), this doesn't actually rule out the idea of seeing arithmetical in terms of a broader idea of rule-based deductions from axioms, see my answer [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/90311/10780).

Comment: @Ajax In your edit you say that it was you who calls Turing's analysis a mathematical analysis because it brings 'algorithms under the purview of mathematical techniques'. Usually one analyzes algorithms concerning their running time, their need of resources, whether they are runnig sequentially or in parallel. - But these are not typical questions from mathematics. Mathematics proves theorems about the relations between abstract objects in domains like number theory, algebra, complex analysis ... 1/2

Comment: @Ajax Hence you may split your question into two questions: 1.) With respect to which properties does one analyze algorithms? 2.) Which type of questions are typical in mathematics? 2/2

Comment: @JoWehler - If you analyze algorithms in terms of some abstract [model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation) like a Turing machine (rather than an engineering analysis of specific physical computing machine) I would say that's definitely a mathematical question--for example, the truth or falsity of P=NP is considered an important unsolved mathematical problem. The bottom of p. 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409142.pdf) also mentions that computer scientists have defined axiomatic systems for dealing with questions about programs.

Comment: @JoWehler, There are two kinds of mathematics associated with algorithms. Theory of computation deals with algorithms as abstractions and with the kinds of systems they can be executed on. It is as much mathematics as mathematical logic is (in fact, there is a lot of overlap). On the other hand, analysis of algorithms deals with specific algorithms and ways to compare them. You could say analysis of algorithms is not mathematics but an application of mathematics like theoretical physics is an application of mathematics.

Comment: It is the rigorous treatment of some concept, subject of study with the method and language (using symbols) of *mathematics*: definitions, axioms, theorems.

Comment: In the same sense that Euclidean geometry is the mathematical theory of *space*, so Turing theory is the mathematical theory of *algorithm* or formal computation and Hilbert's proof system is the mathematical theory of *deduction*. What is the benefit? we can express rigorously property of the "mathematized" concepts: e.g *consistency* for formal deductive systems, termination for algorithms, etc.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And is Goedel's theorem (incompleteness) a mathematical theory of *logic*? Perhaps if not theory, but mathematical *analysis* of logic?

Comment: Goedel's theorem expresses a specific property of formal systems "including" (in a specified sense) enough resources to express "arithmetical facts". It is mathematical logic, of course.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Then was it Goedel who initiated mathematization of logic (or mathematical logic)?

Comment: No: Boole,Peirce,Frege,Russell,Hilbert.