# We know Classical Mechanics is wrong. But can we also say every other theory is wrong except the Theory of Everything?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics, physics, quantum-physics

Classical Mechanics (CM) or Quantum Mechanics (QM) is technically wrong. That doesn't mean they are irrelevant or have less significance, but they are wrong regardless of how accurate they are. Can we also say the same thing about Quantum Field Theory (QFT) or General Theory of Relativity (GR) because they are not The Theory of Everything (ToE)?

Or should we use the term 'correct but incomplete' for QFT and GR and 'accurate but wrong' for CM and QM?

Update: I see some confusion in the comments and answers due to the ill-posed nature of my question. Let me be more specific. As @Causative pointed out, I agree that CM is more wrong than QFT/GR. But I am hesitating to accept that the same can be said of QFT with respect to the ultimate ToE. Because to my best knowledge, we can apply CM to any particle but the position it predicts would be slightly off from the actual position. This slight inaccuracy gets bigger when the particle is of very high speed or of microscopic scale. This I don't think is the case with QFT. In QFT, we cannot apply this theory to let's say describe the interaction between galaxies. We need GR for that. However, using GR we cannot describe the interaction between 'point particles'. It's not the case that we can and it gives inaccurate results. We cannot apply. So, to me probably the problem with QFT and GR is that they are successful in their own domain but we don't have a unified theory. If we can unify them, we will have the ToE. However, if I am wrong in my premise, then it seems that even after we successfully uinify GR and QFT, the ToE will still be inaccurate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137250/discussion-on-question-by-earman-we-know-classical-mechanics-is-wrong-but-can-w).

Comment: [All theories are wrong, but some are useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong)

Comment: @MarkDominus indeed, and the reason why some are useful is precisely because they are simplifications of reality (and therefore wrong to some extent).  The only thing that *exactly* represents reality is reality and if we could understand that we wouldn't need models/theories.

Comment: How does the actual Question hold logic, please?

If you're really Asking "Can we say every theory is wrong except the Theory of Everything" why not Ask that, without reference to classical mechanics?

I believe that in logic, philosophy as here, and physics "We know Classical Mechanics is wrong" is merely a statement; worth its own value, but neither part of nor any basis for an argument.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I admit that my wording of the question is very bad. I tried to clarify my question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715027/how-to-use-gr-instead-of-qft-or-vice-versa-if-possible-at-all-in-the-sense-t). Actually to better put my question, I'd say "Every theory is approximate, i.e., incorrect to some extent and sense. Is QFT/GR incorrect in the same sense as CM? or is there anything special in QFT/GR (as I think there is)?

Comment: @Earman Thanks. Why not take all of that into account and either Edit, or Delete and replace the badly-worded Question? Why would that be difficult? How could that be unreasonable?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - I don't wanna edit the question further because many people have already responded to the question I originally asked. Anyway, please use [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137250/discussion-on-question-by-earman-we-know-classical-mechanics-is-wrong-but-can-w) for further discussion instead of a comment.

Comment: @Earman If you don't wanna Edit something you yourself describe as very badly worded, why would anyone want to go to Chat with you? If you can't bring yourself to Edit this thread why not take the helpful option, leave this thread and Post a new one, better worded? How hard could that be?

Answer (score 35):

Asimov's "[The Relativity of Wrong](https://hermiene.net/essays-trans/relativity_of_wrong.html)" has a lot to say about this.

> John, when people thought the Earth was flat, they were wrong. When people thought the Earth was spherical, they were wrong. But if you think that thinking the Earth is spherical is just as wrong as thinking the Earth is flat, then your view is wronger than both of them put together.

Yes, classical mechanics is wrong. There isn't even any restricted domain in which classical mechanics is perfectly right. Quantum mechanical or relativistic effects are always slightly present, even at mundane scales and energies, making the predictions of classical mechanics always a tiny bit off. The same can be said of GR, or QM, or essentially any theory of physics that isn't the ultimate TOE.

So these fields are wrong - but they are also *mostly right* in certain domains, and that is important. Truth is [fuzzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) in the sense of fuzzy logic. Science, when done properly, usually tends to get closer and closer to the actual truth. It may never at any point in time be completely right, but it is *more* right than it was before, and more right than the alternatives.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137287/discussion-on-answer-by-causative-we-know-classical-mechanics-is-wrong-but-can).

Answer (score 33):

It is not a coincidence that you ask this here at philosophy SE, and not over at physics: The vast majority of physicists would simply reject your question and readily admit that their theories are *both* incomplete and, to varying degrees, inaccurate. They are pretty hardcore [*pragmatists:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth#Pragmatic) A theory is good if it is more consistent with past observations and predicts the future better than its predecessors. Most of them would reject the idea that they are in the business of discovering absolute truths, and probably even reject the idea that those can ever be discovered *in principle,* which is mostly equivalent to the idea that they don't exist: Nature is "infinitely deep". If you continue to drill somewhere you'll discover new things.

What we have now is a set of theories like Newtonian mechanics or general relativity. Some of them — typically the younger ones — are more consistent with observations than others, and they often contain unintuitive fundamental assertions: Even very small masses attract each other, there is an upper limit of speed, physical quantities are not continuous but quantized.

These fundamental assertions that lead to good predictions take on the role of  "insights" into how the world works, how it *is.* But that is more a mental convenience than a "fundamental truth": If we accept the idea that nature is "infinitely deep", these assertions are necessarily incomplete. The discovery of new insights may later render them fundamentally *wrong.* For example, Newton was revolutionary in carving out the fundamental laws governing the interaction of masses. His theory continues to give good predictions (and thus is pragmatically very true for engineers concerned with objects at human scales). But it is utterly wrong in its fundamental assertions, most spectacularly with his underlying assumption of immediate interaction between distant objects. This is just not how the world works.

The same can be said about general relativity with its fundamental concept of a continuous spacetime. This is just not how the world works.

My gut feeling is that *everything* we assume about the world is utterly wrong on a fundamental level. Nature is infinitely deep. The journey of discovery will never end. New fundamental assertions will continue to supersede and obsolete previous ones.

If that seems unsatisfactory we can take pride in the fact that our theories are already quite consistent with observations, and enormously helpful. Cars drive, factories work, houses and bridges don't collapse, spacecraft follow their trajectories if our incomplete and inaccurate theories are properly applied.

Comment: I really like this answer, because it asserts that scientific theory is not concerned with being "right" or "wrong". Each theory has its limits. The terms "more right" or "more wrong" don't really make sense. Scientific theories are phrased as "more accurate" or "less accurate" compared to observations. Newton's theory of gravity was accurate enough to take humans to the moon for the first time in history, and predict the return of Haley's comet decades after Isaac's death, but not accurate enough to pinpoint your location on Earth using GPS.

Comment: "Cars drive, factories work ...".  This sentences summarizes the flaw in OP's question.

Comment: "All we ever do is learn the laws of the trellis, to better understand the rose" - Nick Mulvey, Venus

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth explicitly pointing out that there is no reason to believe that there is such a thing as a "theory of everything". Such a theory would imply that the universe perfectly follows some mathematical principles, but there is no reason why this needs to be the case. When physicists talk about a theory of everything, what they really mean (I think, most of the time), is a single theory that gives our best approximation of everything we observe, as opposed to having separate theories for gravity and, say, electromagnetism.

Comment: Hi Peter, I asked this question in Physics SE where I formulated my question very precisely. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715027/is-it-even-possible-to-use-gr-instead-of-qft-in-the-sense-that-its-possible-to

Comment: @Earman Hm, it was not well received. It seems to me that quantum field theory and general relativity describe very different aspects of nature, and it is unclear to me how each could be used instead of the other. Everybody would love to "unite" them but since even Einstein failed who was ... for the lack of a better term, the instigator of of both relativity and quantum theory, I'm not overly optimistic.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, We use the word 'unification' in the case of GR and QFT, but note that we don't use such wording in the case of CM and SR. We didn't need to unite CM and SR. If you use SR for low-speed particles, you'll automatically get the same(or extremely near) answer that you'd get using CM. Then why do use such wording in the case of QFT and GR? That's my point. 1/2

Comment: (contd.)  I am saying either show me that we can analyze the same system using both GR and QFT (like we did in CM and SR), or if you can't like you said that they are meant to be used in very different aspects of nature, then QFT and GR should be given some special status than CM, SR, QM and so on. That's why I said maybe we can say that CM, SR, QM - are incorrect(and incomplete), but QFT and GR are not incorrect but only incomplete. 2/2

Comment: I responded in a series of comments to your question on the physics stack exchange--as I said there, for various systems that would require quantum gravity to treat fully accurately you can still analyze them with *approximate* combinations of QFT and GR, similarly if you have a field theory like classical electromagnetism that can only be treated fully accurate in SR, you would need an approximate version of the field theory to analyze things in CM. So I don't think there is any obvious disanalogy between QFT/GR being approximately true wrt quantum grav and CM being approximately true wrt SR.

Comment: @RonJohn, I'd say this sentence rather conflates science and technology. Technology is a very useful byproduct of science, but fundamental science couldn't care less. For the sake of argument, Einstein came up with the idea of relativity to free electrodynamics from luminiferous aether, not to fix that annoying problem with GPS clocks. If it existed at the time, it would be, to a theorist, “a very curious observation that doesn't fit the theory,” not “a problem that needs a solution.” An engineer, on the other hand, would just tweak the clock rate and shrug it off. :)

Comment: @kkm I'd almost think the opposite of your description of engineer vs. scientist is true: The *theorist* is very excited about persistent and reproducible deviations from predictions, no matter how small (because they show that the theory is deficient), while the engineer couldn't care less about deviations that are small enough, e.g. smaller than production tolerances. Complementing that, GPS following GR predictions to the letter are frequently mentioned as validation of the theory.

Comment: Peter, my point exactly! Sorry, I likely wasn't clear. What I meant was that science is not concerned with producing technology ("couldn't care less"), even though it incidentally gives rise to it. Our theorist would absolutely get excited by the deviation from theory—to satisfy his curiosity, not because GPS (stuff in the realm of technology) needs a fix. He doesn't care if “cars run, factories work.” Out of context, this can't "expose flaws" in the Q (not that there are none. :) OP seems unaware of the real tongue-in-cheek meaning of "ToE"). And your A is the best, IMO, given the sloppy Q.

Comment: @kkm engineers use formulas based on Classical Mechanics.  If cars built using those formulas **did not** run, and factories built using those formulas didn't work, that would be an indication that Classical Mechanics (which is Relativity with accuracy and precision Good Enough for 99.9% of the macro world at non-relativistic speeds) is wrong.  But they do run and work, so Classical Mechanics *is* "right".

Answer (score 3):

Every physical theory may be either wrong or incomplete. This is because mathematics is used as a language to describe physics and we have [Gödel's incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)

But this is just to say that we can't ever be sure about correctness and completeness at the same time. It may, however, be the case that we eventually find a theory that perfectly describes whatever we seek to describe and that does not leave room for logical contradictions, e.g. by using only a finite number of axioms and so forth.

Finally, it must be said that we can never prove a theory of everything right. This is because the description of the extremely early and the extremely distant future universe are by definition not observable by humans and hence unscientific. Not 100% sure about this point but confident enough to put it here. As always, open to discuss anything :-)

Comment: Godel's incompleteness theorem is about arithmetic, and some theorems of arithmetic might require checking an infinite number of cases, as I discussed in [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/90311/10780). So, it might be that for such theorems, one could always find a physical system such that if it *ever* exhibits a certain behavior in an unlimited period of time, the theorem would be false, and otherwise it would be true.

Comment: (cont.) In that case, Godel's incompleteness theorem might say that there's no physical theory that can tell us in a finite number of computations whether a physical system will ever exhibit a certain behavior in an infinite period. However, this is not normally what theories of physics are intended to do; instead, they usually give dynamical equations that can be used to predict the behavior of any physical system over a *finite* time interval. I don't think Godel's incompleteness theorem would give us any reason to think we can't find a fundamental theory that does that.

Comment: The Godel [in]completeness theorems are probably the most famous and the least understood among general audience. They're concerned strictly with _formal logic systems,_ narrowly, foundational axiomatisation of math. The incompleteness theorems prove statements about, roughly speaking, a formal system that is “sufficiently powerful” to express statements about itself. E.g., Peano arithmetic is, but Presburger arithmetic, geometry or linear algebra aren't.The result is inconsequential to applied math, and so to physics. Then, physics uses math to speak about the world, not about physics. :)

Answer (score 3):

An engineer does not view a theory from the viewpoint of whether its predictions are 100% correct to the utmost limit of precision. Instead, an engineer judges a theory based on the question, "Can I use this theory to get stuff done?"

From that perspective, classical mechanics *is* correct for a mechanical engineer. He can build a bridge that will carry its load or build a plane that safely arrives at its intended destination, all based on classical mechanics. Many applications don't even need to account for the curvature of the earth; they're designed as if the earth were flat and everything still works.
(That being said, I do not recommend hiring a flat-earth theorist for an engineering position.)

While it's true that steel, concrete, combustion and electricity ultimately get their properties from quantum behavior, the engineer does not need to know this. He/she only needs to know how these things behave within the intended environment. For most applications, the effects of quantum mechanics and general relativity are not an issue, because they are swamped by the other uncertainties and variations that engineers have to accommodate in their work.

Comment: Exactly. A driving car is a marvelously complex machinery, yet, apart from the electronics, it's 100% classical mechanics. You don't even need a generator to build a functioning car, nor a spark plug (diesel engine with mechanic injectors). You don't need to have heard about quantum mechanics or relativity to understand the operation of an assault rifle, or to know about earth curvature/rotation to operate one. Really, there's a reason why we didn't discover modern physical theories sooner...

Answer (score 1):

Each theory in natural science has a bounded domain of validity. I consider this a basic insight, well-known to each working scientist.

A 'Theory of Everything' does not exist. The term contradicts all scientific experiences.

Which argument does support the idea, that adhering to the idea of an all-embracing theory is a useful heuristic? The omniscient dwarf exists only in fairy tales :-)

Comment: So you endorse some notion of [strong emergence](http://consc.net/papers/emergence.pdf) where the regular behaviors seen in fields like biology and meteorology are not even in principle derivable from fundamental physics acting on initial physical conditions? This view would likely be a minority one among working scientists. See for example Einstein's comment [here](https://www.site.uottawa.ca/~yymao/misc/Einstein_PlanckBirthday.html) in the paragraph beginning 'In my belief the name is justified...'

Comment: @Hypnosifl I do not speak neither about emergence nor about reductionism. My point is to emphasize that new fields of observation often require new concepts, which did not even existed before, e.g., electromagnetism, spacetime, quantum effect.

Comment: But are you just talking about new discoveries in fundamental physics requiring new concepts, or are you talking about new concepts in macro fields e.g. the principles of darwinian evolution not being conceptually self-evident from quantum field theory? In that case, a believer in weak emergence could agree such principles are conceptually novel even if all the relevant behaviors of biological systems would be in principle derivable from quantum field theory alone given sufficient computational power and knowledge of the initial conditions of biological systems and their environment.

Comment: Also, when you say the idea of a theory of everything "contradicts all scientific experiences", are you in fact denying that we might someday discover a final theory of fundamental physics from which all other phenomena are derivable *in principle*, the same way the behavior of all the higher-level patterns in [the Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), like "gliders" and such, are derivable from the underlying simple rules? Dennett discusses the analogy with The Game of Life at length in chapter 2 of *Freedom Evolves*.

Comment: +1 The comments are off-topic. Theories are wrong in so far that there are false statements when using it out of useful boundaries. And yes, Theory of Everything contradicts itself - this is more about Gödel's theorem than about emergence.

Comment: @rexkogitans - I don't think the comments are off-topic, they relate to the meaning of "Theory of Everything"--it seems like Jo Wehler is either A) asserting without argument that the various domains of different scientific theories rules out the possibility of a "theory of everything" in the sense of a fundamental theory that all other empirical observations are *in principle* derivable from, or B) treating "theory of everything" as a master theory that would allow for *practical* or *conceptual* derivation of all other theories, which would be a strawman, no scientist uses the term that way.

Comment: As for Godel, presumably you are using that to argue for A), but if Jo Wehler is asserting A), my objection is that no specific argument is presented to back it up. You're free to write up your own answer involving Godel's theorem, but just know that Godel's theorem is specifically about the impossibility of a formal system which can determine the truth or falsity of every statement about arithmetic in a finite no. of steps; even if we did know the correct final theory of fundamental physics  I don't see how that would help us determine the truth-value of arbitrary arithmetical statements.

Comment: @ Hypnosifl My argumentation against the usefulness of the concept of a final theory, which allows to derive all particular physical theories, is based on the following two points: 1) Opening up new domains of observation often required new concepts and new ideas. These ideas did not exist before. 2) The human mind is bounded like the mind of all other livings. Therefore I assume the existence of concepts and insights about nature which are not reachable even for the human mind.

Comment: @Hypnosifl, w.r.t. the Einstein's statement, note the important restriction “if that process of deduction were not far beyond the capacity of the human intellect.” This is where the notion of strong emergence is rooted. We can write down the general Navier-Stokes equation for compressible flow; what we cannot do is solve it to describe turbulence in a meaningful way. We cannot describe and study the brain in the framework of QM by writing down its Hamiltonian, which is possible, but only _in principle._ Reduction is not wrong, it's merely useless in some cases.

Comment: @kkm - That's not what strong emergence means as defined in the [Chalmers paper](http://consc.net/papers/emergence.pdf) I linked to--he says it means "the high-level phenomenon arises from the low-level domain, but
 truths concerning that phenomenon are not deducible even in principle from truths in the low-level domain". Also note I used the phrase "in principle" in all of my first three comments, I wasn't talking about whether the high-level behavior is deducible in practice from fundamental physics.

Comment: @Hypnosifl, The Q was about scientific theories, and every theory, epistemologically, _starts_ by carving its objects from the world, only _then_ describes their properties, behavior etc. No idea what C. calls "phenomena,"  he's both radical and careless in terminology (his ridiculous "zobmies" are so ill-defined!); in general sense, they seem to match _observables_ of a theory. _Of course_ incompatible theories work with different objects and observables! Geometrical optics, wave optics and QED objectivize light in incompatible terms, each defines own observables. He makes a non-statement.

Comment: @kkm - "High-level phenomena" doesn't require situating things in a theory, it's about anything that could be measured using some kind of physical measuring-instrument (this paper has nothing to do with his metaphysical speculations about non-empirical entities like zombies, not sure why you bring that up here). For example, if the system being measured is a human and the measuring-instrument is a keyboard that records keystrokes, strong emergence about human behavior would say it's impossible *in principle* to derive the characteristic text-patterns made by a person from fundamental physics.

Comment: @Hypnosifl So called "fundamental" theories in physics don't consider "human" or "keyboard" objects or "keystroke rate" an observable, thus "in principle" is a non-statement. You can try to reduce w/o correspondence, e.g. by writing QM equations describing the human and the keyboard, but that's “far beyond the capacity of the human intellect.” There's a misconception that "human" and "typing rate" are self-evident without a theoretical framework admitting a definition or at least a sound operational description of the former and a measurement procedure for the latter. It's absolutely not so.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Re zombies, only as an example of Chalmers's sloppiness in definitions and language use. This lack of care can, and even tends to create a lot of apparent paradoxes.

Comment: @kkm "You can try to reduce w/o correspondence, e.g. by writing QM equations describing the human and the keyboard, but that's “far beyond the capacity of the human intellect." But here you're just returning to the issue of practical difficulties, ignoring the issue of whether it's possible in principle, which is the defining question of whether you have "strong emergence" or not.

Comment: Also note that in modern terms, the difficulty is computational, not a matter of needing a super-human intellect to invent new concepts--with a powerful enough computer one could just simulate the quantum state of all the particles making up human + keyboard, and as long as the physical system contains records recorded in terms of position states of some kind ('pointer states' in von Neumann's sense), one could use a simulated version of the Born rule at the end to see what had been typed in the simulation, likewise for any other type of measuring instrument that records data digitally.

Comment: Incidentally, it's off-topic here but I disagree there's anything particularly sloppy about Chalmers' analysis of zombies. Analytic philosophy tends to presuppose the idea of something like an exhaustive set of true propositions about the world, and the defining feature of any non-materialist metaphysics is therefore that there'd be some additional true propositions beyond an exhaustive set of material truths (truths about mathematical statements that no physical system ever computes the answer to, for ex.)--Chalmers is assuming that truths about subjective experience fall into this category.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Why is this even a question? If A and B sit down for a game, and A plays chess but B plays trumpet, is it worth the effort to philosophize inability to establish a way to score this game into "strong emergence?" To answer your question, it's beyond the capacity of at least my intellect to say yes or no. Seems possible on the surface, but would possibly run into entropy capacity effects, like Maxwell's demon paradox. QM is a bitch. But simply from practice of theorizing, reducing to QM is certainly not a tractable approach to _understanding_ how the typing human works. :)

Comment: @Hypnosifl, careful with computation and QM. Every particle adds dimensions to the infinite dimensional state space, and the Universe can contain only so much information.

Comment: I don't understand how inability to "score" a game that has no rule-set is supposed to be an analogy for questions about strong emergence. As to why strong emergence is even a question, I'd say theoretical science is always in part driven by beliefs that there's an objective truth about how nature really works, and that theories about this can drive a lot of research even if "fully" testing them is beyond our practical capabilities for the forseeable future. As an analogy, consider Darwinian evolution as a sort of "grand unified theory" of adaptive evolution;

Comment: it's obviously beyond our practical ability to have strong evidence that every single adaptive change came about through the same mechanism of random mutation and natural selection, but the working hypothesis that this is true can help continually drive new research about the history of specific adaptations, and each partial success gives more reason (in some sort of inductive or Bayesian sense) for favoring the broad theoretical claim. Similar with theory reductionism, we can continue to research various kinds of partial reductions, like explaining more aspects of biology in terms of biochem,

Comment: explaining more and more of chemistry using ab initio quantum methods, and so on, even if the process of reducing one level to another is never complete but always a work-in-progress.

Comment: As for computation and QM, it's true the full computations might be infinitely complex but a sufficiently good discrete approximation would still likely be able to reproduce observations about discrete pointer-states of measuring instruments. And there is also theoretical reason to think current continuous quantum theories are just approximations to a more accurate theory that would only allow finite volumes of space to have states of finite complexity, due to the theoretical arguments for the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) as part of quantum grav.

Answer (score 1):

A Theory of Everything would require knowledge of everything for it to be a correct theory. So, by this reasoning, all theories are wrong until the knowledge of everything is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Your question tacitly assumes that, because our physical theories cannot predict the behavior of objects to perfect precision, those theories are wrong.  **That conclusion is intuitive, but in fact need not follow.**

**Other answers here argue that our physical theories are *approximately true***, because, once we restrict our ability to measure to some limited domain, the theories then predict the behavior of objects.  (Larger domains of measurement then correspond to truer theories.)  That approach is certainly one way to dissolve the difficulty.

**But there is another approach**, as expressed in (for example) [S. Smith (2002) "Violated Laws, *Ceteris Paribus* Clauses, and Capacities," *Synthese* 130](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1014422011637).  In Smith's approach, physical theories do not even *attempt* to explain the behavior of objects; they are not sufficient to that end.  But they are *necessary*.  Some objects *O* exhibit behaviors *B* of such import that any theory that does not incorporate *B* cannot hope to predict future behaviors of *O*.  By that standard, all known physical theories, not just the hypothetical "theory of everything," are true, because they summarize known important behaviors.